# Slow download speed when using PHP header:location

Tags: php, apache

There are two servers

1. Application server (Apache)
2. File Server

I tested the download speed between Server1 and Server2 and it is approx. 10 MBPS.

I tested the download speed on Server1 by downloading some files from the internet and got 25 MBPS speed.

I downloaded the files directly from the Server2 to my computer and get around 10 MBPS speed.

But when I redirect a download from PHP script the download speed is no more than 500 KBPS

Here is my code:

```
  $xml_content = file_get_contents(array_get_by_index($rp, $stack));
        $name        = basename(array_get_by_index($rp, $stack));
        header("Content-type: application/xml");
        header('Content-disposition: inline; filename= ' . $name);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Connection: keep-alive");
        echo $xml_content;
        flush();
        ob_flush();
```

Comment: What does "header:location" have to do with anything…?

Comment: Why the download is slower when going through PHP can have many reasons: 1) you're reading the file into memory and then echo it to the web server, which then outputs it. There can be a lot of swapping and buffering going on there. 2) How exactly are you measuring the speed? Since PHP buffers the file first, perhaps that time lag simply cuts into the average speed calculation. 3) Yes, this will be inefficient either way. You should let your web server serve the file in some fashion or another, don't preoccupy PHP with it. How to do that exactly depends on the details here.

Comment: I mean when using this method to download the files the speed decreases. I don't know if it affects the file download speed

Comment: You're reading the entire file into memory before sending it. That's never going to be as fast as reading and sending small chunks, which is probably what any sane web server does.